# How to Increment count based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to extract a new column based on a condition so the new column will act as a counter and it will just count if `(MessageDate1- MessageDate2).TotalMinutes > 10`.

For example if i've the following input:

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╗
║ ConversationId ║     MessageDate1      ║     MessageDate2      ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║              1 ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:16 AM ║ 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:20 AM ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:16 AM ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:20 AM ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:05:03 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:09:03 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:05:03 PM ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:03 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:09:03 PM ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:04 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:03 PM ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:05 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:04 PM ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:22:06 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:05 PM ║
║              1 ║ 2/17/2012 11:05:03 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:22:06 PM ║
║              1 ║ 2/17/2012 11:09:03 PM ║ 2/17/2012 11:05:03 PM ║
║              1 ║ 2/17/2012 11:11:03 PM ║ 2/17/2012 11:09:03 PM ║
║              2 ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:18 AM ║ 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  ║
║              2 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:18 AM ║
║              2 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:02 AM ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║
║              3 ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:50 AM ║ 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  ║
║              3 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:50 AM ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:50 AM ║
║              4 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:04 AM ║ 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  ║
╚════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

So the output would be:

```
╔════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╦═════════╗
║ ConversationID ║     MessageDate1      ║     MessageDate2      ║ Counter ║
╠════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╬═════════╣
║              1 ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:16 AM ║ 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  ║       1 ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:20 AM ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:16 AM ║       2 ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:20 AM ║       2 ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:05:03 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║       3 ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:09:03 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:05:03 PM ║       3 ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:03 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:09:03 PM ║       3 ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:04 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:03 PM ║       3 ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:05 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:04 PM ║       3 ║
║              1 ║ 2/16/2012 11:22:06 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:11:05 PM ║       4 ║
║              1 ║ 2/17/2012 11:05:03 PM ║ 2/16/2012 11:22:06 PM ║       5 ║
║              1 ║ 2/17/2012 11:09:03 PM ║ 2/17/2012 11:05:03 PM ║       5 ║
║              1 ║ 2/17/2012 11:11:03 PM ║ 2/17/2012 11:09:03 PM ║       5 ║
║              2 ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:18 AM ║ 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  ║       6 ║
║              2 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║ 2/15/2012 11:53:18 AM ║       7 ║
║              2 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:02 AM ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:01 AM ║       7 ║
║              3 ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:50 AM ║ 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  ║       8 ║
║              3 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:50 AM ║ 2/16/2012 11:53:50 AM ║       8 ║
║              4 ║ 2/16/2012 11:54:04 AM ║ 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM  ║       9 ║
╚════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: So what have you tried, why didn't it work?

Comment: You can use the ROW_NUMBER function.
this link should be useful :
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu, I've tried the sum() function with condition but it didn't work

Comment: @MohanadShamsneh . . . Ordering seems important to your question, but there is no column that carries the ordering information.  SQL tables represent UNORDERED sets.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, i've added a new column to the data may it help, also i can generate a row number for all the data

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a column that specifies the ordering, then you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum():

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_md2 > dateadd(minute, -10, messagedate1) and
                     prev_md2 < dateadd(minute, 10, messagedate1)
                then 0 else 1
           end) over (order by <ordering col>) as grp
from (select t.*,
             lag(messagedate2) over (order by <ordering col>) as prev_md2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: i've the prev_md2 column already, i just need to add ... i don't know why the then, else, end, case .... is not supported in my case


       SUM(CASE WHEN(MessageDate1 - MessageDate2 ).TotalMinutes > 10 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY Id) AS GenSessionId

Comment: @MohanadShamsneh . . . Use the date/time logic from this query.  Your code is not correct syntactically.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up some dummy data to mirror your stated question:

```
create table some_data
(
    id int,
    MessageDate1 datetime,
    MessageDate2 datetime
)

insert into some_data values
(1,'2012-02-15 11:53:16', '2012-02-15 00:00:00'),
(2,'2012-02-16 11:53:20', '2012-02-15 11:53:16'),
(3,'2012-02-16 11:54:01', '2012-02-15 11:53:20'),
(4,'2012-02-16 23:05:03', '2012-02-16 11:54:01'),
(5,'2012-02-16 23:09:03', '2012-02-16 23:05:03'),
(6,'2012-02-16 23:11:03', '2012-02-16 23:09:03'),
(7,'2012-02-16 23:11:04', '2012-02-16 23:11:03'),
(8,'2012-02-16 23:11:05', '2012-02-16 23:11:04'),
(9,'2012-02-16 23:22:06', '2012-02-16 23:11:05'),
(10,'2012-02-17 23:05:03', '2012-02-16 23:22:06'),
(11,'2012-02-17 23:09:03', '2012-02-17 23:05:03'),
(12,'2012-02-17 23:11:03', '2012-02-17 23:09:03'),
(13,'2012-02-15 11:53:18', '2012-02-15 00:00:00'),
(14,'2012-02-16 11:54:01', '2012-02-15 11:53:18'),
(15,'2012-02-16 11:54:02', '2012-02-16 11:54:01'),
(16,'2012-02-16 11:53:50', '2012-02-16 12:00:00'),
(17,'2012-02-16 11:54:50', '2012-02-16 11:53:50'),
(18,'2012-02-16 11:54:04', '2012-02-16 00:00:00')
```

I've included an `id` field to allow me to order the records as I could not see any particular logic to how your sample data was ordered and the way the count works is dependent on the order of the records. I also replaced date values you had for the year `0001`.

This query gives what I believe the desired output is, where the `Count` is incremented each time a record is encountered where the difference between the `MessageDate1` and `MessageDate2` fields is more than 10 minutes:

```
select
    MessageDate1,
    MessageDate2,
    sum(GT_10M) over (order by id) as [Count]
from
(
    select
        id,
        MessageDate1,
        MessageDate2,
        case when abs(datediff(minute,MessageDate2,MessageDate1)) > 10 then 1 else 0 end as GT_10M
    from some_data
) r
```

Results:

```
/-----------------------------------------------------------\
|      MessageDate1       |      MessageDate2       | Count |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------|
| 2012-02-15 11:53:16.000 | 2012-02-15 00:00:00.000 |   1   |
| 2012-02-16 11:53:20.000 | 2012-02-15 11:53:16.000 |   2   |
| 2012-02-16 11:54:01.000 | 2012-02-15 11:53:20.000 |   3   |
| 2012-02-16 23:05:03.000 | 2012-02-16 11:54:01.000 |   4   |
| 2012-02-16 23:09:03.000 | 2012-02-16 23:05:03.000 |   4   |
| 2012-02-16 23:11:03.000 | 2012-02-16 23:09:03.000 |   4   |
| 2012-02-16 23:11:04.000 | 2012-02-16 23:11:03.000 |   4   |
| 2012-02-16 23:11:05.000 | 2012-02-16 23:11:04.000 |   4   |
| 2012-02-16 23:22:06.000 | 2012-02-16 23:11:05.000 |   5   |
| 2012-02-17 23:05:03.000 | 2012-02-16 23:22:06.000 |   6   |
| 2012-02-17 23:09:03.000 | 2012-02-17 23:05:03.000 |   6   |
| 2012-02-17 23:11:03.000 | 2012-02-17 23:09:03.000 |   6   |
| 2012-02-15 11:53:18.000 | 2012-02-15 00:00:00.000 |   7   |
| 2012-02-16 11:54:01.000 | 2012-02-15 11:53:18.000 |   8   |
| 2012-02-16 11:54:02.000 | 2012-02-16 11:54:01.000 |   8   |
| 2012-02-16 11:53:50.000 | 2012-02-16 12:00:00.000 |   8   |
| 2012-02-16 11:54:50.000 | 2012-02-16 11:53:50.000 |   8   |
| 2012-02-16 11:54:04.000 | 2012-02-16 00:00:00.000 |   9   |
\-----------------------------------------------------------/
```